# Get the Session ID from the fe_typo_user Cookie when I can't get it from the request itself by using [...]\Core\Session\UserSessionManager or similar

Tags: php, typo3, service-worker, extbase, typo3-11.x

To retrieve the User from the fe_typo_user Cookie-Value sent via JS "fetch" within a POST-Body, I require a workaround. Due to the usage of "fetch" inside a Service Worker for my POST-request to TYPO3, TYPO3 lacks the ability to independently access the user Session from the Cookie.

In simple terms, I have access to the value of the fe_typo_user Cookie and I want to manualy retrieve the Uid (User ID) of the fe_user.

---

The TYPO3 version I am using is v11.5, and I have a custom Extbase Controller implemented.

---

**Edit:**
I'm just sending a fetch request like the following:

```
  fetch("https://myDomain.tld/home/web/create/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ cookieValue: cookie}, null, 2)
  })
```

Since the request is sent from a Service Worker, which does not have access to cookies or the DOM, TYPO3 is unable to retrieve the User automatically.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way using fetch on the client side, is preventing you from picking up the session in Typo3 on the server side?

Comment: @CBroe does my Edit provide enough Information?

Comment: You will have to find the matching record in the `fe_sessions` table then, I think - only the session id stored in there does not appear to directly match the cookie value, I would assume it probably gets hashed with a salt or something.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too... It's clear that there should be a way to decrypt or obtain the session ID (ses_id) since TYPO3\CMS\Core\Session\UserSessionManager::createFromRequestOrAnonymous() performs a similar task. However, I was wondering if there is an API available specifically for this purpose. @CBroe